# Attempt to access the method failed: System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor()

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I've this code through which I am retrieveing json data from my Localhost.But it is giving the error mentioned in my title.When I hover over the response while debugging.It shows me the correct response.I am using JSON.NET to parse json response.

```
var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                   List<Company> cLst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(response);    //Error

                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {

                            foreach (Company c in cLst)
                            {
                                ListBoxItemControl Li = new ListBoxItemControl();
                                Li.CompanyNameTextBlock.Text = c.CompanyName;
                                Li.PromotionTextBlock.Text = c.PromotionText;
                                listBox1.Items.Add(Li);
                            }
                        });
```

Here is the Company Class.

```
class Company
{
    public string CompanyName {get; set;}
    public string CompanySlogan { get; set; }
    public string CompanyDescription { get; set; }
    public string CompanyRating { get; set; }
    public string CompanyDpPath { get; set; }
    public string CompanyOtherInfo { get; set; }
    public string CompanyFollowers { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public int PromotionID { get; set; }
    public string PromotionText { get; set; }
    public string PromotionRating { get; set; }
    public string PromotionPicPath { get; set; }
    public string PromotionTitle { get; set; }
    public int PromotionLikes { get; set; }
    public int PromotionComments { get; set; }



}
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another class like,

```
 public class RootObject
 {
  public List<Company> companies;
 }
```

And then modify your code like this,

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
List<Company> cLst = jsonData.companies;
```

Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the Company class public