# Handling JSON in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, json.net

I have a JSON file coming from the internet:

```
string JSON = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

It works perfectly, the problem is here:

```
NewsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(JSON) as News;
```

**This works perfectly on WP8 project, but WP7 somewhy fails it**. Here is my News class:

```
    class News
    {
        [JsonProperty("jsonrpc")]
        public string Jsonrpc { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        private List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
        [JsonProperty("articles")]
        public List<Article> Articles { get { return articles; } }
    }
    public class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public long Date { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("imageURL")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the error:

**Attempt to access the method failed: WP7RTURelease2.HomePage+News..ctor()**

System.MethodAccessException was unhandled
  Message=Attempt to access the method failed: WP7RTURelease2.HomePage+News..ctor()
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.LateBoundReflectionDelegateFactory.<>c_*DisplayClass6`1.b*_5()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultConstructor)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
       at WP7RTURelease2.HomePage.HandleResponseNews(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Comment: Possible diplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783327/attempt-to-access-the-method-failed-system-collections-generic-list1-ctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your `News` class public.